# c++ template char class

Tags: class, templates, char

I can't find the problem. I am trying to use `char` as parameter for a class template:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class Type1, class Type2> class myclass
{   
    Type1 i;
    Type2 j;
public:
    myclass(Type1 a, Type2 b) {i=a; j=b;}
    void show() { cout << i << ' ' << j << '\n'; }
};

void main()
{   
    myclass<int, double> ob1(10, 0.23);
    myclass<char, char *> ob2('X', Just show ");
    ob1.show();   
    ob2.show();
}
```

Comment: So, what is your problem? What goes wrong? Also, please format your code next time.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what your problem is...

Comment: Running this in ideone does seem to work fine. http://ideone.com/xF9wC

Comment: Mhm, but in visual studio it not work

Comment: @user1069874: So how exactly does it not work? Tell us the compiler error (or on the off change that it compiles, but crashes where and how it crashes)

Comment: `error C2065: 'Just' : undeclared identifier
error C2001: newline in constant
error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'show'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an opening quote before `Just`:

```
myclass<char, char *> ob2('X', Just show ");
//                             ^ 
// should be:
myclass<char, char *> ob2('X', "Just show");
```

Note though that you should use `const char*` when you want to allow passing string literals and that this has ownership issues. Preferrably use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `"` in `myclass<char, char *> ob2('X', Just show ");`, it should be `myclass<char, char*> ob2('X', "Just show ");`. Furthermore the type should probably  `myclass<char, const char*>` instead of `myclass<char, char*>`